# argument of $\dfrac{i}{\bar{z}^{2}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $arg z\equiv \dfrac{\pi}{6} (\textrm{mod}\ 2\pi)$ then calculate:

$$arg \dfrac{i}{\bar{z}^{2}} $$

indeed,

$$
\begin{align*}
arg \dfrac{i}{\bar{z}^{2}}&=arg i - arg\bar{z}^{2} \\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2arg\bar{z} ( \forall n\in \mathbb{N},\quad \arg(z^n)\equiv n\cdot\arg z\mod 2\pi\;)\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2\dfrac{-\pi}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\\
&=\dfrac{5\pi}{6}
\end{align*}
$$

- can i use Wolframe alpha to calculate that directly

Comment: Why is it important to say that $\arg i=\frac{\pi}2 (\mod 2\pi)$ rather then saying that $\arg i=\frac{\pi}2$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: Yes. But when you calculate $\overline z$ or ${\overline z}^2$ or when you divede $i$ by ${\overline z}^2$ you don't need this.

Comment: Yes, in that case i'll write equal $=$ instead of Modular $\equiv$

Comment: I attempted an answer because I could write such a long comment. I don't see how the modular exposition changes the argumentation below.

Answer (score 2):

**A lengthy comment**

As shown pictured below

[image]

the following operations take place:

$$\arg i=\frac{\pi}2$$ and $$\arg z=\frac{\pi}6.$$
Then
$$\arg \overline z=  -\frac{\pi}6$$
and
$$  \arg {\overline z}^2=-\frac{\pi}3.$$

So, $$\arg \frac i{  {\overline z}^2}=\frac{\pi}2 + \frac{\pi}3=\frac56\pi.$$

Where exactly would change the result that we've been using modular arithmetic?